# Page refreshes twice after updating datas

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, vscode-extensions

**Update Information first**

The cause for question is found. For solution/reason see end of this posting ...

---

Here is some PHP code to update a data row in a SQLite database using PDO:

```php
$db = new PDO("sqlite:$db_name");   
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$update_data = array(
    'animal' => 'cow',
    'name'   => 'Mary',
    'age'    => '4',
);

$stmt = $db->prepare( "UPDATE $db_table SET animal = :animal, name = :name, age = :age WHERE id = 48 "  );
$stmt->execute($update_data); 

echo $stmt->rowCount();
```

The (to me) strange behaviour is, that the page in the browser loads the page twice when this code is executed.

**NOTE:** this happens only if the data in the database changed. If the update data are identical with DB data (so there is no change in the DB) the page only loads one time.

The effect is the same:

- when only this the code is on a plain PHP page (= initialize a new page load -> the page loads correct -> the DB action happens -> page automatic refreshes to load second time - why?)
- or if I initialize the code by a form request (= submit form -> action leads to the same page -> page loads correct -> after processing POST data the code with this DB action is executed -> page automatic wants reload second time - why?)

This effect does not exist when I run the same code in a MySql database (tested on a Maria DB):

```php
$db = new PDO("mysql:mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tst_animals", 'admin', 'admin' );  
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$update_data = array(
    'animal' => 'cow',
    'name'   => 'Mary',
    'age'    => '4',
);


$stmt = $db->prepare( "UPDATE $db_table SET animal = :animal, name = :name, age = :age WHERE id = 5 "  );
$stmt->execute($update_data); 

echo $stmt->rowCount();
```

This code is executed after the page has loaded without a automatic page refresh.

Can anyone explain the strange behaviour to me?

- What in this code is the reason for the automatic page reload?
- How can I avoid the automatic page reload (the idea is: the database action executes and nothing on the page itself changes)?

Thanks for all answers.

**PS**:

- Please notice that this has nothing to do with try{...}catch(){...}. Using the code with try/catch shows same effect. I just reduced the code for testing and simplifying the issue here and tested it with/without try/catch as well.
- The tested behaviour is the same if the code with the DB action is executed before (or even after) something has written to the page.

---

---

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION**

As in the comments was a remark that the code does not work here the working example for 'PDO sqlite', - I only added the variable settings, sorry for the little abstraction:

```php
<?php

$db_name = "D:/xampp/htdocs/devClassForm/system/sqlite/db_animals.sqlite";
$db_table = "animals";

$db = new PDO("sqlite:$db_name");   
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$update_data = array(
    'animal' => 'cow',
    'name'   => 'Mary',
    'age'    => '4',
);

$stmt = $db->prepare( "UPDATE $db_table SET animal = :animal, name = :name, age = :age WHERE id = 48 "  );
$stmt->execute($update_data); 

$stmt->rowCount();
```

DB table settings are:

- [id, integer, autoincrement, primary key]
- [animal, text]
- [name, age]
- [age,integer]

When testing please fill database and adapt id number in statement to your settings.

The plain code indeed works proper as it is. I copied it direct one to one from testing file , - but concerning the insisting comments I checked the code once more and found the solution for the very strange and irritating behaviour.

When I tested I used VS Code with Live Server Extension. This setup in Firefox (not tested with Chrome...) indeed causes the auto refresh of the page (checked in the Server logs).

Deactivating this extension the code works as well, updates db data and the page only loads once.

Thanks for the help :-)

(I suggest to let this posting stay here and not to delete it even it is not really a coding issue. Maybe this information about the testing setup helps someone else some time to save time.)

Comment: My Guess is we will need to see the page code html and an javascript

Comment: _"when only this the code is on a plain PHP page"_ This can not be true, as the code you've posted won't work by itself. I.e., you've edited out the code that's causing the problem.

Comment: Due to the comments I checked the code and tested it once more. Indeed the code works proper as it is: it just updates the DB data in the intended way. I added the variable settings and posted the code without the little abstraction once more so it can be tested by direct copying it (but you have to adapt the variable settings). But when testing I found the reason: when I tested I used 'VS Code with Live Server extension activated'. See end of the posting. I Updated the posting that way.  Thx for the comments at all. It indeed helped to find the solution.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer instead of editing your question.